# Asterisk suffix (*) on any Element data type (analyzer >= 0.40.0)

Tags: dart, dart-analyzer

After upgrading to 0.40.0 I started getting an awkward asterisk suffix sign after any type.

Example...

`print(elementInstance.type.toString());`

I used to get `Stream<bool>` now I'm getting  [`Stream<bool*>*`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fkdkg.png)

Do I miss any analyzer settings or dart formatting?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

It says just that a variable could be either nullable or non nullable because such behaviour was before NNBD (Dart v.2.12) where you have to explicitly mark a variable with question mark if it is nullable

Check out this article https://dart.dev/null-safety

Answer (score 1):

We can simply use Element's new method `getDisplayString()` which has a bool parameter `withNullability`.

Based on the @Andrey Gritsay's comment I conducted a quick debug into the analyzer package and found it.